# Allow specific users to access application on hosting

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am going to publish my application on hosting, i already decided which hosting i going to buy. I want to be able to deny anybody to view that app from the web except some people who will be tested that.

I not sure is hosting usually allowing to do some thing similar, to set some options or any IP address restrictions to app. I know that it is possible to do in IIS but not sure if hosting allowed direct access to IIS. Otherwise i need to implement that in my app.

What is you experience with that?

My app build on asp.net mvc 3.0.

Hosting i choose arvixe.com (didn't buy yet). I asked them that question on email but didn't get any response yet

Answer (score 1):

As you have already indicated it is so easy to restrict / allow specific IP addresses with IIS. But on your case it is possible that your provider won't give you the permission to tweak  this section.

What you can do is to create a HttpModule and restrict the IP addresses by this way. Here is great example of this implementation :

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/http-module-ip-security.aspx

Here is the code for this :

```
/// <summary>
/// HTTP module to restrict access by IP address
/// </summary>

public class SecurityHttpModule : IHttpModule
{
 public SecurityHttpModule() { }

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(Application_BeginRequest);
    }

    private void Application_BeginRequest(object source, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpContext context = ((HttpApplication)source).Context;
        string ipAddress = context.Request.UserHostAddress;
        if (!IsValidIpAddress(ipAddress))
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 403;  // (Forbidden)

        }
    }

    private bool IsValidIpAddress(string ipAddress)
    {
        return (ipAddress == "127.0.0.1");
    }

    public void Dispose() { /* clean up */ }
}
```